# error: 'GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure' names the constructor, not the type

Tags: c++

Whenever I build this code, I always get the "error: 'GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure' names the constructor, not the type".

I've already tried removing the GenericEnclosure:: with a new error then showing.

.cpp file

```
  GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure frontLeftEnclosure{name, m_leftFrontDriveMotor, m_leftFrontTurnMotor, m_leftFrontTurnEncoder, 0.1};
```

.h file

```
class GenericEnclosure : public SwerveEnclosure {
public:
    GenericEnclosure(   std::string name,
                frc::SpeedController& m_moveMotor,
                frc::SpeedController& m_turnMotor,
                rev::CANEncoder& m_encoder,
                double m_gearRatio);
    ~GenericEnclosure();
```

From this, I would have hoped that it would build properly but there is something going on that I can't recognize. I still don't understand the source of the problem because I am new, so anything will be appreciated.

Edit: I was right to remove the GenericEnclosure:: but I now get this error

```
undefined reference to `GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, frc::SpeedController&, frc::SpeedController&, rev::CANEncoder&, double)'
```

Comment: Present your [mcve], per the instructions.

Comment: If you already solved it, but encountered a different problem, perhaps tell us what _that_ problem was..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I never said I solved it

Comment: *I've already tried removing the GenericEnclosure:: with a new error then showing.* That was the right thing to do. Adding the other error so we can help you kick it in the teeth is in your best interests

Comment: The *undefined reference* error message means the linker could not find where the constructor was defined. You may have forgotten to actually give the constructor a body or maybe you forgot to compile and link the file containing it. [Many other possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but those would be the big two.

Comment: @user4581301 I made an edit and added the new error

Comment: @user4581301 what do you mean by give the constructor a body?

Comment: `GenericEnclosure(parameters go here);` promises that somewhere else this function will be fully defined. [It declares but does not define the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration). There needs to be a `GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure(parameters go here) : initialize class member variables here { maybe do some other stuff here }` to fulfill the promise made by the declaration and this definition must be compiled and made visible to the linker.

Comment: @user4581301 so i need to put the GenericEnclosure:: back and use GenericEnclosure elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The way how you should write the definition of `GenericEnclosure`'s constructor:

```
GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure(std::string name,
                                   frc::SpeedController& m_moveMotor,
                                   frc::SpeedController& m_turnMotor,
                                   rev::CANEncoder& m_encoder,
                                   double m_gearRatio)
{
  // something goes here
}
```

The way how you should declare a variable of type `GenericEnclosure`:

```
GenericEnclosure frontLeftEnclosure{name, m_leftFrontDriveMotor, m_leftFrontTurnMotor, m_leftFrontTurnEncoder, 0.1};
```

So `GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure` tells, that you declare a variable of type `GenericEnclosure` in namespace `GenericEnclosure`, but it seems it isn't so.

**UPD** If you haven't defined the constructor (and all the declared methods), you can't declare a variable, your second error tells about it.

Comment: I just tried defining and i got this error cannot define member ```cannot define member function 'GenericEnclosure::GenericEnclosure' within 'Robot'
                                      double m_gearRatio){}```